# Google Maps API v3 Display Travel Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using Google Maps API v3, is it possible to get the travel time to display when the map is opened initially?

There's an example at [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-travel-modes) of switching between travel modes. I know how to set an `addEventListener` to listen for an `input` `change` and then display the travel time, but I want to display the driving time when the map is first opened / loaded.

I am opening the map in a modal window.

The following JQuery works when I change inputs, but not initial open. It works on the **second open**.

```
$('#travelTime').html('Est. travel time: ' +travelTime);
```

The code below works, although it doesn't contain a modal.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Travel Modes in Directions</title>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
    <b>Mode of Travel: </b>
    <select id="mode">
      <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
      <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
      <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
      <option value="TRANSIT">Transit</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <p id="travelTime"></p> <!-- display time here -->
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 14,
          center: {lat: 37.77, lng: -122.447}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        document.getElementById('mode').addEventListener('change', function() {
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        });
      }

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
        directionsService.route({
          origin: {lat: 37.77, lng: -122.447},  
          destination: {lat: 37.768, lng: -122.511},  
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            travelTime = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text; // contains correct value 
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to pass calculateAndDisplayRoute as a callback. Not sure whether it will fix the issue.

Comment: THanks, but i'm not sure what that means or how to achieve it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise the map before opening the modal.

Add `initMap()` on page load.